# window.onerror and javascript console errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling

I have following code to capture errors in javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onerror = function(msg, url, linenumber) {
      console.log('Error message: '+msg+'\nURL: '+url+'\nLine Number: '+linenumber);
      return true;
   }
</script>
```

I opened chrome developer console and going to generate `ReferenceError` by random javascript code. Lets say:

```
person.run();  // person object does not exist
```

It throws `Uncaught ReferenceError: person is not defined` and printed in the console. But it is not captured by `window.onerror`. Why?

Comment: the code should run without issues, are you sure you're not running person.run before you load the onerror, or is there something else that could interfere

Comment: I am just typing `person.run()` in chrome developer console. I want to know errors happen in chrome developer console(by your own try out codes) captured by `window.onerror`?

Comment: try window.alert(window.foo)

Comment: @mplungjan What do you mean?

Comment: Try something that might invoke a window error

Answer (score 3):

An event handler for runtime script errors.

Note that some/many error events do not trigger window.onerror, you have to listen for them specifically.

open this link this is use full for you:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onerror

Answer (score 0):

For console or for other browser app

```js
 document.onerror=function (errorMsg, url, lineNumber,colNumder,error){
    console.log('OnError');
     return true
}

function consoleErrorTrap(call){
    try{
        return call();
    } catch(e){
        let event= new ErrorEvent('error',{error:e})
        document.dispatchEvent(event);
    }   
}

consoleErrorTrap(()=>{
    throw new Error()
})
```

Comment: If the consoleErrorTrap function is declared in the context of DOM or loaded scripts, then you can do with the `call()` code, without `try{}catch({}`
since the error will bubble up in the DOM context and run the trigger (dispatchEvent) automatically